# Set macOS audio output to an iOS device

Tags: macos, ios, audio, speakers

The speakers of my computer have a bad crackling sound. I'd like to be able to watch videos on my computer (for the large screen) and have the sound on the iPhone speakers (better sound). Is it possible ? And if yes, how ?

Comment: This may or may not work, but connect your iPhone via USB/Lightning cable then open Audio Midi Setup (found in Utilities Menu).  If you see your iPhone listed as an output device - enable it.   Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Allan Indeed, the iPhone is listed when plugged to the laptop, but it can only be used as an input device, the output tab is disabled.

Comment: Is there a button to enable anywhere?

Comment: I couldn't find any.

Comment: Then it’s not available, unfortunately